# Laravel Eloquent multiple relations of many-to-many between models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have a few models that should relate, in a many-to-many relationship (I presume), for the following:

My Clinic has many practice areas (ex. odontology, psychiatry, general medicine, internal medicine, etc. and operates in several global continents/world regions, in many countries of each region and in many cities of each country. Not all clinic branches have the same Practice Areas.

Where my difficulty comes is because of the following:

1. The Clinic is in many World Regions/Continents;
2. It is also, in many Countries of each Region
3. It is also in may Cities of each Country;
4. Each Clinic branch will have it's own Practice Areas;

My first approach was too clunky and would't work for sure, as I tried to build a pivot table with more that two ids and the other was to do it in one table (which I presume is absolutely incorrect).

What would be the best approach to set the database for all these relationships to work together, with the following models I have:

```php
Models\Clinic::class;
Models\PracticeArea::class;
Models\WorldRegion::class;
Models\Country::class;
Models\City::class;
```

```php
Models\Clinic::class;

public function areas() {
    return $this->belongsToMny(PracticeArea::class, 'area_clinic_counrty', 'area_id', 'country_id', 'clinic_id');
}
```

To simplify, the form has a multiple-select for each region, and each Country (let's discar the Cities here). I would like to add/update/delete by using the `sync()` method for the pivots table when the json response is posted. Ex:

```php
data: {
clinic_id: 2,
practices: { 
    1: ["12","31], // the keys correspond to world region in this ex.
    3: ["7", "12", "42"] // the values to practice areas ids
}}
```

Thanks in advance on any insights on how to best set this, because in fact I'm quite new to the Eloquent relationships at this advanced level.

Comment: What is a clinic branch? The part of a clinic that is operating in a certain country?

Comment: Hi Jonas, yes, The Clinic has it's headquarter address (Address::class), then it has several "branches" or addresses throughout the world and each one will have its specific practice areas. Ex. In Hong Kong it may have General Medicine and Oriental Medicine, while in NY it may have different practices areas, Thank you

Comment: Is there a separate model for the branches? Or is a branch a combination of clinic and city?

Comment: Yes, I call it the Address::model, which has the `firm_id`, `city_id`, `country_id` and `region_id` among the normal address fields

Comment: So shouldn't you define a `BelongsToMany` relationship between `Address` and `PracticeArea`?

Comment: That's probably where I'm stuck. I'm trying to do it all with the `Models\Clinic::class` and probably the mess is about that, Because when I try to update the pivot tables in some I get errors other don't sync. I'll take your suggestion and try to recode from scratch this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Jonas Staudenmeir suggestion and help, I ended up solving the problem with one simple pivot table and the respective methods for the relationship. Thus the following, in case someone has the same issue:

Created a migration for the pivot table

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('address_area', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('address_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('area_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->primary(['address_id', 'area_id']);
    });
}
```

Now, on the `App\Models\Address::class` added the method for the relationship:

```php
/**
 * Method to establish the relationship between the address and the practice areas
 *
 * @access public
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 * @since  1.0.1
 */
public function areas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(PracticeArea::class);
}
```

On the other end, the `App\Models\PracticeArea::class` added the method for the relationship:

```php
/**
 * Method to establish the relationship between the practice areas and the address
 *
 * @access public
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 * @since  1.0.1
 */
public function address()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Address::class);
}
```

Now, every time it's added or removed a practice area on the clinic branch, which has the `city_id`, `country_id` and `region_id` columns, the pivot table is then synced:

```php
// synchronize (add/delete) entries on the pivot table
// $practices array of practice areas
$address->areas()->sync($practices);
```

This way, multiple queries can be done on both sides – Clinic branches or Practice areas by city, country or region.